# Fitting data using a series of Sin and Cos

Tags: fitting, trigonometry

I have the following data representing the normal displacement caused by a normal load applied at the middle cross section of a cylinder:

[image]

I've made [the data available here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/benmzocau8qa17g/fitting-data-representing-the-displacement-of-a-cylinder-with-a-normal-load-at-t.zip).

I am trying to fit using the function:

$$
w=\sum_{i=1}^{n} A_{i}\cdot sin(j\theta)+B_{i}\cdot cos(j\theta)
$$

where $A_{i}$ and $B_{i}$ are the unknown amplitudes to be found. I am using `LeastSquares` for this task:

```
theta = data[[All, 1]];
w = data[[All, 2]];

num = Dimensions[theta][[1]];
n = 5;

m = Table[
   Flatten[Table[{Sin[i1*theta[[i2]]], 0}, {i1, 1, n}]] + 
    Flatten[Table[{0, Cos[i1*theta[[i2]]]}, {i1, 1, n}]], {i2, 1, 
    num}];
x = LeastSquares[m, w];

f[t_] := Total[Flatten[Table[{Sin[i*t], Cos[i*t]}, {i, 1, n}]].x]
Plot[f[t], {t, -Pi, Pi}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {0, 0.030}}]
```

But it is resulting in an empty graphic:

[image]

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your data is screwy - using exponentiation with `e` has no meaning to *Mathematica*. Format it correctly and if you still have problems, update the data link.

Comment: Wouldn't `Fourier` be better for this than fitting ... ?

Comment: @Saullo Castro Boa pergunta! Estava tendo o mesmo problema. Nos fóruns brasileiros é difícil obter uma resposta e aqui em São José dos Campos quase ninguém mexe com estas coisas...

Comment: @LCarvalho sim... a solução sempre são os forums em inglês

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After patching your data and fixing/adjusting code (removed unneeded `Total`, upped samples):

```
theta = data[[All, 1]];
w = data[[All, 2]];

num = Dimensions[theta][[1]];
n = 150;

m = Table[
   Flatten[Table[{Sin[i1*theta[[i2]]], 0}, {i1, 1, n}]] + 
    Flatten[Table[{0, Cos[i1*theta[[i2]]]}, {i1, 1, n}]], {i2, 1, 
    num}];
x = LeastSquares[m, w];

f[t_] := Flatten[Table[{Sin[i*t], Cos[i*t]}, {i, 1, n}]].x
Plot[f[t], {t, -Pi, Pi}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {0, 0.030}}]
```

[image]

Comment: And to make this fitting success, the index of fitted function should start from $i=0$ :)

Comment: @xzczd thank you for this comment, indeed there are cases where the series must start with $i=0$